# React.js - Creating Simple Accordion example

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm relevantly new to React and I am having trouble on how to tackle this logic:

Essentially I am creating a table using flexbox, and I also want it so that when you click on one of the rows, it expands and reveals another row (for example, it will give a small description what it is about).

So far what I have is just the table.

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const renderDataRows = (
      [
                <div key={0} className='row'>
                    <div className='cell description'> Mortage Bill
                    </div>
                    <div className='cell amount'>$0,000,000</div>
                    <div className='cell amount'>$2.50</div>
                    <div className='cell amount'v>000%</div>
                </div>,
                <div key={1} className='row'>
                    <div className='cell description'> Electric Bill
                    </div>
                    <div className='cell amount'>$0,000,000</div>
                    <div className='cell amount'>$2.50</div>
                    <div className='cell amount'v>000%</div>
                </div>,
      ]
        )


    const containerTable = (
            <div className='table-container'>
                {renderDataRows}
            </div>
        )
    return (
      <div>
        {containerTable}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

More specifically, what would be the best way to structure the hidden rows? Create as a child of the cells, or siblings?

I am assuming I will need state to keep in track what is current open, etc?

I've attached [Codepen](http://codepen.io/neotriz/pen/XRJQVJ) link to mess around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in the following way:

Let all the `cells` be in a single parent div and let the cell description be another sibling div (although using  would be better). Put a class on the sibling div such as `hidden`. Not add a click handler on the `cells` div. Whenever this div is clicked, update the state with that div's id/key. Now use this to set the **`hidden`** class to the other divs. Compare **`this.state.key`** with the current id/key and show or hide accordingly. I am not giving the specific code.

**Note:** Instead of storing the divs in the renderDataRows, just put the data in it and map over it to create all the divs. That way you can easily manipulate the `hidden` class and any other variation in a single place without having to update it separately for each row of data.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Does that imply that if I have +100 rows, I have to keep track of all +100s row states?

Comment: No. You can just put one key/I'd element in the state holding the "active" or open accordions I'd/key

Comment: Let me know if you need help with the same. If you have managed to do it, try and add a fiddle here so as to help others having similar issues. Thanks. Also accept answer if it helped.