# Transition flexbox items on button click

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to create a component similar to [the component that shows the NBA schedule at the top](https://www.nba.com/) or the component that allows you to navigate to different weeks on the [nfl](https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule) site. When you click the buttons on the side, the items in the flexbox slide to the left or right.

I'm using dates in my example. I don't have any problems make it look how I want it to look, but I'm not sure how to go about implementing the click feature that will adjust the items in the flexbox when click either button. Nothing has come up while trying to research a similar component.

Here's what I have so far:

**App.tsx**

```
import "./App.css";

function getDaysInMonth(month: number, year: number) {
  const date = new Date(year, month - 1, 1);
  const days = [];
  while (date.getMonth() === month - 1) {
    days.push(new Date(date));
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  }
  return days;
}

function App() {
  const dates = getDaysInMonth(12, 2023);
  console.log(dates[0]);

  return (
    <div className="p-8">
      <div className="w-full border text-center bg-zinc-200 mb-2">
        <h1>App</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="flex gap-2">
        <button className="border w-24 hover:bg-zinc-200">L</button>
        <div className="mx-8 border max-w-screen h-12 flex gap-4 items-center justify-start overflow-x-auto">
          {dates.map((date) => {
            date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            const month = date.toLocaleString("default", { month: "short" });
            const day = date.getDate();
            console.log(month + day);
            return (
              <div
                key={day}
                className="border text-sm flex p-2"
                onClick={() => console.log("clicked " + month + day)}
              >
                {month} <span className="ml-1">{day}</span>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
        <button className="border w-24 hover:bg-zinc-200">R</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**App.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: "the items in the flexbox slide to the left or right." kind of sounds like an accordion element. Example https://stackoverflow.com/q/64039485/125981 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/43422555/125981

Comment: It's like an accordion but not exactly (at least based on all of the accordion components that I've seen). The first link provided no help, but the second link gave me a few ideas! Thank you.